# Update trigger to track last update date (SQL 2008 R2)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm looking for a model for keeping a last update timestamp on all records in a set of tables.  One idea was to implement this with triggers so that no matter how a record got updated, the DateLastUpdated column would keep up to date.

Given a test table called Data_Updata, this is my current update trigger which ensures 
the data is updated.  Looking at the query execution plan when I run this, the trigger takes 56% of the time.  Is there a more efficient trigger/sql to use?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Data_Update]
   ON  [dbo].[Data_Trigger]
   FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE
        [Data_Trigger]
    SET 
        DateLastUpdated = GetDate()
    FROM
        [Data_Trigger] data
    JOIN
        inserted ON data.DataID = inserted.DataID
END
```

Comment: Do you need to know the actual datetime that the modification occurred, or are you using this as some kind of mechanism to coordinate some further activity (e.g. something else tracks the `MAX(DateLastUpdated)` it last saw, then requests rows with a greater `DateLastUpdated`) - if the second, you could use `rowversion`, which is maintained by SQL Server automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Very likely, the join between `[Data_trigger]` and `inserted` uses a `TABLE SCAN/CLUSTERED INDEX SCAN` on `[Data_trigger]` table.

What can you do ?

Check cached plan for this trigger:

1) First, run this query to find `plan_handle` for your object(trigger):

```
SELECT  t.name AS TriggerName
        ,ts.*
FROM    sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats ts
INNER JOIN sys.triggers t ON ts.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE   ts.database_id = DB_ID()
AND     t.name LIKE '%Audit%';
```

2) Second, find the cached plan (XML). For example, if the plan handle for this trigger is `0x050009009A0A677BB8E09C7A000000000000000000000000`, you can use this query to find cached plan:

```
DECLARE @plan_handle VARBINARY(64) = 0x050009009A0A677BB8E09C7A000000000000000000000000;
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_plan(@plan_handle) qp;
```

If the join between `[Data_trigger]` and `inserted` use a `CLUSTERED INDEX SCAN` for `[Data_trigger]` then you have (at least) three options in `SQL Server 2008`:

1) `UPDATE STATISTICS` on  `[Data_trigger]` table: [updating statistics causes queries to recompile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx). After this operation, test trigger and check again cached plan to see if it uses `SEEK`.

2) Or, you can rewrite the `JOIN` from `UPDATE` using one `IN` subquery:

```
FROM
    [Data_Trigger] data
WHERE data.DataID IN (SELECT DataID IN SELECT inserted)
```

After this operation, test trigger and check again cached plan to see if it uses `SEEK`.

3) If `SEEK` operator is not used then you can [use `FORCESEEK` table hint (new in `SQL Server 2008`; also see Best Practice Considerations section)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510478.aspx):

```
FROM
    [Data_Trigger] data WITH(FORCESEEK)
JOIN
    inserted ON data.DataID = inserted.DataID
```

For `TABLE SCAN` try creating an unique (clustered or clustered) index on `DataID` column.